# HintLayout для hintContent

Tags: javascript, json, api, yandex-maps-api

Необходимо добавить на карту 70+ объектов. Добавляю через objectManager, данные для карты берутся из json-файла.

Я прописал шаблон для хинта, он работает, если я добавляю одну метку. Но если я передаю описание объектов в json, то не могу применить шаблон. Как нужно написать то?

Вот сам шаблон:

```
    HintLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass( "<div class='my-hint' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'>" +
        "<img src='map/faces/{{ properties.a_face }}.png'><br />" +
        "<span class='a_name'>{{ properties.a_name }}</span>" +
        "<span class='a_sport'>{{ properties.a_sport }}</span>" +
        "<span class='a_city'>{{ properties.a_city }}</span>" +
        "</div>"
    );
    //хранилище стилей
    ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('mypreset', {
        hintLayout: HintLayout
    });
```

На карте заместа хинта получаю `[object Object]`.

Вот пример из json-файла.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [63.160232, 92.356094]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": {
          "a_face": "0",
          "a_name": "Azat",
          "a_sport": "Football",
          "a_city": "Ufa"
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "preset": "mypreset"
      }
    }]
  }
```

[вот тут собранный пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXJgEG)

Answer (score 1):

В общем всем спасибо за участие)
Как оказалось это баг в API Yandex Maps.

[вот ответ тех.поддержки.](http://clubs.ya.ru/mapsapi/replies.xml?item_no=58781) как только поправят баг - отпишу решение.